# steps to setup portforwarding

Tags: redhat, port-forwarding

I have a java process running on a server[SlaveServer]. I like to attach java debugger on a certain port say 19999.The problem is the server isnt directly reachable from my local pc .
Below is how i login to Slave server.

I ssh to the Master and then from Master only i can access the slave via ssh.

localpc[Windows7]----->MasterServer[RH Linux]---->SlaveServer[RH Linux]

The port 19999 on slave is the one i want to connect from local pc.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSH Port Tunneling, example is Putty.

After you run putty, go to "Connection, SSH, Tunnels", put 19999 as the source port, and SlaveServer:19999 as the destination, and add the new the new forwarded port.

Then, go to "Session", and type the hostname MasterServer, and login via SSH as normal.

After you are logged in to MasterServer via SSH, as long as the putty window is open, any traffic to localhost:19999 will be forwarded to SlaveServer:19999.